# How to add a close button to NgZorro Collapse header component?

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular7, ng-zorro-antd

I am working on NgZorro Collapse component. I have to add a close button on the top-right of the component. How to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
  <nz-collapse>
      <nz-collapse-panel [nzExtra]="extraTpl">
      </nz-collapse-panel>
  </nz-collapse>
  <ng-template #extraTpl>
     <i nz-icon nzType="close" nzTheme="outline"></i>
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: do you know how can I pass data to the template, plsssss

Comment: found it, need just to add the template inside the nz-collapse, thanks